# Value of type "UIImageView" has no member 'rating'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I have been following the Developing IOS Apps (Swift) Guide that Apple has provided. I am trying to load in a variable called `rating` that was set in another file called `RatingControl` and trying to access it in a file called `MealTableViewController`. If I understand this correctly, the line of code is trying to access the variables from the file/class `RatingControl`.

When trying to access the value of the variable like this:

`cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating`

I get an error stating:

> Value of type "UIImageView" has no member 'rating'

What is this error telling me and how would I solve it? I am clueless on how to read/handle this error. I have programmed with Golang/C# for quite a bit now, but Swift is different.

Comment: It seems like it is trying to get the variable from a class called 'MealTableViewCell' and getting the value the tutorial told me to add to the file (MealTableViewCell) and the variable is a UIImageView.

Comment: Could you define IB please?

Comment: IB means Interface Builder as you can see in the screenshot below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the class name in identity inspector.

[image]

Comment: I just checked and it shows the Class is RatingControl.

Comment: @HubbA did you create iboutlet for this in UITableViewCell class?

Comment: Check `MealTableViewCell` class for this line `@IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!`

Comment: @Rajesh outlets cannot be connected to repeating content. OP will need to subclass UITableViewCell

Comment: I have one right here in the TableViewCell Class file called (MeatTableViewCell) @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: UIImageView!

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm asking op to check UITableViewCell subclass only. I assume OP has created UITableViewCell subclass and created outlet there.

Comment: @HubbA thats the mistake. `ratingControl: UIImageView!` it should be as `ratingControl: RatingControl!`. Disconnect the iboutlet connection and create outlet again.

Comment: @HubbA ratingControl should be a UIStackView not an UIImageView

Comment: @LeoDabus RatingControl is a subclass of UIStackView he has created and assigned it.

Comment: @Rajesh I know it is a subclass  of UIStackView but he is connecting the wrong object

Comment: @HubbA You should show your tableview cellForRow method

Comment: @HubbA make sure you delete the old connection right clicking the image view in the IB

Comment: Yep, that worked, deleting the old connection and making a new one. Thank you very much. To Clarify what worked (For others maybe in this situation) it was changing the UIImageView to RatingControl. Thank you for the help everyone!